# "Чтобы не пропустить новые видео" or "новых видео"?

Tags: выбор-слова, падежи, множественное-число

Is it grammatically correct to say:

"Подпишись, чтобы не пропустить новы**х** видео"

or should I say:

"Подпишись, чтобы не пропустить новы**e** видео"?

Please, instead of just saying which option is right, provide some explanation and sources.

Comment: Sorry, I do not think, that my answer should be accepted as the best one. At least I am no sure that the correct usage is the usage of genitive. I have simply meant that even for the native speakers the correct usage is not  obvious. Check [here]( https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/443857/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5)

Comment: Based on the experience of a native speaker I would say that in the positive statement the use of genitive case sounds unnatural and is definitely incorrect. I.e.  "Я пропустил новых видео" is definitely incorrect. However, neither of two negative statements "Я не пропустил новых видео" and "Я не пропустил новые видео" sounds as unnatural as the previous positive statement. Moreover, I personally feel that both are correct, but have some subtle difference in the meaning. However I cannot explain it.

Comment: @SimonE your examples are not the same as in the question.

Comment: @SimonE - Somebody once told me that it's a case of Oжидательный падеж, placing more emphasis on the action rather than on the direct object. Thus, "Я ожидаю поезда Москва-Санкт-Петербург" would stress the action of waiting (rather than the train), while "Я ожидаю поезд Москва-Санкт-Петербург" draws more attention to the object (that is, to what train exactly is being awaited).

Comment: @brilliant You can say "я ожидаю новых видео от этого автора" and that would be correct (ожидательный/partitive case). This would mean some new videos as opposed to the new videos. But your example is wrong. Maybe because it implies "definite article" while partitive has the opposite meaning, so it looks like "the some new videos".

Comment: @Anixx - I don't see how, while "Я ожидаю новых видео от этого автора" is correct, "Подпишись, чтобы не пропустить новых видео (от этого автора)" is wrong. Both imply "some new videos".

Comment: @brilliant interesting question but it sounds utterly wrong. By the way, "Подпишись, чтобы не пропустить никаких новых видео от этого автора" sounds okay.

Comment: When looking at your example, I feel that you refer to the videos as to animate objects which makes weird sensation. Like in "смотри внимательно, чтобы не пропустить новых ящиков" as if ящики were some guys.

Comment: @Anixx - But "Подпишись, чтобы не пропустить новых видео от этого автора" sounds okay to me.

Comment: No, this is ungrammatical and sounds like if videos were animate persons.

Comment: @Anixx - If we keep exchanging such arguments like "it sounds like" or "to me it sounds", we won't arrive at anything. Some authoritative sources are needed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem can be restated as whether the direct object видео should be used in genitive case or accusative case. It is not as straightforward as VaNdal tried to convince you.

Wikipedia states that the direct object is used in Russian mostly in accusative case and *sometimes* in genitive case after transitive verbs.
[*Выделяют прямое дополнение — беспредложное дополнение после переходного глагола (в русском языке — в **винительном**, иногда в **родительном** падеже)*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81)#%D0%92_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5).

I am afraid that this is the case. Like "не пить воды" or "не видеть леса за деревьями".

Comment: This is totally wrong answer. "Подпишись, чтобы не пропустить новых видео" is simply ungrammatical.

Comment: @Anixx Why? Can you provide any sources to support your claim? After all, such phrases like "Мы ожидаем больших паводков и сильных ураганов" (along with "Мы ожидаем большие паводки и сильные ураганы") is absolutely grammatical.

Comment: @brilliant it is ungrammatical as well. If you add не as in  "Мы не ожидаем больших паводков и сильных ураганов" it is okay. If паводки and ураганы were animate, it would be OK as well, as in "Мы ожидаем роботов и пришельцев".

Comment: @Anixx - "it is ungrammatical as well. If you add не as in..." - I would want to know, on the basis of which sources you claim that it is ungrammatical. As far as I know, "Мы ожидаем грозы сегодня" is absolutely grammatical. There is no "не" in it, and ''гроза" is not animate.

Comment: @brilliant "Мы ожидаем грозы сегодня" is correct, it is partitive case "We are waiting for some/any thunderstorm today".

Answer (score 6):

This is an accusative case. "Видео" is inanimate noun.
So, despite the noun itself is unchangeable you need to put the adjective in the correct form.
Thus, only

> "Подпишись, чтобы не пропустить новые видео" (answering the question "Что?")

is the correct option.

If you had a sentence with animate noun it would be

> "Подпишись, чтобы не пропустить новых друзей" (answering the question "Кого?")

Any source of Russian grammar would work here. Like this one
https://www.russianlessononline.com/accusative-case-in-russian-language/

**UPDATE:**

Technically, this is an example of Caritive case, one of the additional cases. Sometimes it's identical to the Genitive and sometimes to the Accusative. Sometimes both form works.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abessive_case#See_also

For the mentioned sentences it is identical to Accusative.

Answer (score 0):

The second is much better, but you can also use singular form "новое видео"

Comment: Why is the singular okay here? Something like a mass noun?

Comment: @Wilson, No, it just has a slightly different meaning with a singular: do not miss one (next?) new video.